# Permissions won't change

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, virtualbox, permissions

I opened Nautilus as super user to try and edit permissions. I can open the drop menu and change, but they instantly revert back to their original state before I can even click "apply changes."

What gives?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Virtualbox machine with a Windows 8.1 host. The folder and it's contents I'm trying to gain access to is a shared folder between the host computer and the virtual machine.

Comment: What permissions are you trying to change? MS Windows filesystems don't support executable status

Comment: Read and write permisions. They are simply imgage files (.jpg and .png) and web development (html, php, css, javascript, etc). I'm currently using dropbox as a workaround, but that only works so long as I have an internet connection and I would really like to get this issue reslved.

Comment: Is it possible the shared folder is read only? Make sure that in VBox settings, the guest can edit the files.